# How to create an instance of System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table in a form (unique question)

Tags: c#, html, winforms

Hi I would like to get all the properties used in System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table which is simple but the catch is that it needs to be done in a windows form application. My actual question is how can I create an instance of System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table in a form

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the WebBrowser control to display HTML.

**EDIT**: To generate the HTML, try the following:

```
var table = new Table();
//Add rows and cells

var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
using (var htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter)) {
    table.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
}
//To get the generated html, use stringWriter.ToString()
```

**EDIT**: Have you considered using a TableLayoutPanel instead?

Comment: Note that we have no idea why he wants to do this.

Comment: I know; that's why I suggested the TableLayoutPanel control.  If he's trying to display other HTML in the table, it'll be useless.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table table = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var table = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table();
```